# How to render another component in nested route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I use 6.8.1 react-router-dom and react is 18.0.9.

How I can render the page in nested route condition (for example: render the page, MemberExample1 in MemberDetail, once it is clicked)?

Here is how the logic flow. It works until I click and (expected) render the page.

1. MemberMgt.tsx ->
2. opened MemberDetail.tsx (from MemberMgt.tsx) ->
3. Click MemberNavbar's one of button. (Should render the page based on its link and path ON MemberDetail.tsx.)

src > routers.tsx

```
const Routers = (): JSX.Element => {
    const location = useLocation();

return (
        <Routes location={location}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
            <Route path="/designsystem" element={<DesignSystem />} />
            <Route path="/modal" element={<ModalPage />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            <Route path="/servermgt" element={<ServerMgt />} />

            <Route path="/membermgt">
                <Route path="" element={<MemberMgt />} />
                <Route path="detail/:id/*">
                    {/* MemberDetail is the page I should render button when clicked. */}
                    <Route path="" element={<MemberDetail />} />
                </Route>
            </Route>
```

MemberMgt.tsx
src > pages > MemberMgt

```
return (
// note: viewList is custom hook. This state refers to the custom hook's state. 
{_.map(state.viewList, (item, key) => {
    <tr
        key={key}
        onClick={(e) => {
        console.log(item.active);
        onChoice(item.id);
        navigate(`detail/${String(item.data.idx)}`, { state: item.data });
        }}
    >
```

MemberDetail.tsx -
This file act as a middle page to display the other page once the button is clicked.

src > pages > MemberMgt> MemberDetail.tsx

```
import MemberBrief from './MemberDetailMenu/MemberBrief/MemberBrief';
import MemberExample1 from './MemberDetailMenu/MemberMsMed/MemberExample1';
import MemberExample2 from './MemberDetailMenu/MemberPoint/MemberExample2';
import MemberExample3 from './MemberDetailMenu/MemberWarn/MemberExample3';
import MemberNavbar from './MemberDetailMenu/MemberNavbar';

const MemberDetail = () => {
// this state does not refer to the custom hook!
   const { state } = useLocation();

   return (
      <div className="title-box">
                <h5>Main - Detail Page</h5>
            </div>
<>
                                        <div className="detail-box-detail">
                        <div className="detail-global-container-gray">
                            <div className="memberNavbar">
                                <MemberNavbar />
                            </div>
                            {/* nested Route */}
                            <Routes>
                                <Route path="*" element={<MemberBrief />} />
                                {/* <Route path="/brief" element={<MemberBrief />} /> */}
                                <Route path="/example1" element={<Example1 />} />
                                <Route path="/example2" element={<Example2 />} />
                                <Route path="/example3" element={<Example3 />} />
                            </Routes>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                </>
            )}
```

Lastly, this is the button, MemberNavbar.tsx.

src > pages > MemberMgt > MemberDetailMenu > MemberNavbar

```
const MemberNavbar = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const param = useParams();

    const handleClickBrief = () => {
        navigate(`/membermgt/detail/${param.id as string}`);
    };
    const handleClickExample1 = () => {
        navigate(`/membermgt/detail/${param.id as string}/example1`);
    };
    const handleClickExample2 = () => {
        navigate(`/membermgt/detail/${param.id as string}/example2`);
    };

    const handleClickExample3 = () => {
        navigate(`/membermgt/detail/${param.id as string}/example3`);
    };
    return (
        <div className="detail-button">
            {/* <Button style="filled" size="md" onClick={handleInfoClick}> */}
            <Button onClick={handleClickBrief} style="transparent" size="md">
                Main - detail page
            </Button>

            <Button onClick={handleClickExample1} style="transparent" size="md">
                Example1
            </Button>

            <Button onClick={handleClickExample2} style="transparent" size="md">
                Example2
            </Button>

            <Button onClick={handleClickExample3} style="transparent" size="md">
                Example3
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: The routing/linking is a bit messy, but I don't *see* any overt issues there. Is there a problem or issue you need help with? Can you clarify what you are asking for help with?

Comment: Thanks. And I guess I found the solution! Here is how I did: add wild card to routers.tsx Route path="detail/:id/*"

Comment: Isn't there already a wildcard matcher there though?

Comment: Yes, the router.tsx one was innocent. It was causing trouble from MemberDetail, the place where nested route exist. I put down wild card mark one at the bottom.